# Binary OSX installer for Python extension without admin rights

Tags: python, macos, distutils, dmg, mpkg

I am packing up a Python extension in an `mpkg`, to create an OSX installer. The `mpkg` is then put in a `dmg` file. This can be done easily with `distutils` and `bdist_mpkg`:

```
python setup.py build_ext
python setup.py bdist_mpkg
hdiutil create -layout NONE -srcfolder $MPKG $DMG
```

The only problem is that `bdist_mpkg` sets the group and mode of the files in the `mpkg` by doing:

```
spawn(['/usr/bin/chgrp', '-R', 'admin', src])
spawn(['/bin/chmod', '-R', 'g+w', src])
```

which fails, because the user building the installer is not in the admin group. The `dmg` is still built, because the `chgrp` and `chmod` are in a `try` block. The `dmg` is built daily, on a build server, and I don't want to give admin permissions to the user that does the build.

My questions would be:

1. Is it really necessary to set the group and the mode?
2. If it is, then can I do it with some tool, after the `dmg` is built?

If there is nothing else, I can write a script to set the group and mode, and then use sudo, but it would be nice to have a proper solution.

Thanks a lot!